# Grid View Auto fit is not showing full images

Tags: android, image, gridview

Why is my Grid View showing images like this?
[image: Grid view from emulator]

My code:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sbsz"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  
</GridView>
```

Image Adapter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LinearLayout linearlayout=new LinearLayout(mContext);
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
         text=new TextView(mContext);
         linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(270, 270));
        text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]); 

          linearlayout.addView(imageView);
          linearlayout.addView(text);
        return linearlayout;
    }

}
```

What's wrong with this code? 
How can I make it to show full images? Shouldn't autofit do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofit means that it will calculate how many 90dp wide columns it can fit. You should change the scale type to center crop, which looks better. And probably use another LayoutParams for the Image, like:
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 120));